# Can you solve these 1st order, 2nd degree equations for me, please?

Tags: calculus

(Context)
So, I want to find by myself the trajectory of an object through atmospheric friction. Given that the norm of the atmospheric friction acceleration vector is: $B{\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert}^2$, where $B=\frac{{Ro}{SC_{fr}}}{2m}$; (m=object mass; $C_{fr}$=friction coeff.; S=object surface area; p=fluid density; ||v||=object speed vector norm), then, with gravity, and knowing the orientation of the atmospehric friction is exactly the speed vector’s orientation θ, less 180 degrees, we have that:
$$\dot{\vec{v}}\{t\}={\frac{d}{dt}}[{\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert}{cos(θ\{t\})};{\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert}{sin(θ\{t\})}]=[-B{\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert}^2{cos(θ\{t\})};-B{\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert}^2{θ(θ\{t\})}-g]$$

So with the product and chain rule on one side, we have, for the x-part of the speed vector’s derivative, that:
$$-{\Vert{{\vec{v}}\{t\}}\Vert}{\frac{d{θ}}{dt}}{sin(θ\{t\})}+{\Vert{\dot{\vec{v}}\{t\}}\Vert}{cos(θ\{t\})}=-B{\Vert{{\vec{v}}\{t\}}\Vert}^2{cos(θ\{t\})}$$
[Which is why I say it’s second degree: there’s ${\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert}^2$]

And, for the y-part:
$${\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert}{\frac{d{θ}}{dt}}{cos(theta\{t\})}+{\Vert{\dot{\vec{v}}\{t\}}\Vert}{sin(θ\{t\})}=-B{\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert}^2{sin(θ\{t\})}-g$$

So a little bit of isolation for ||v’{t}|| to equate the 2 resulting equations finally leaves this weird function:
$${\frac{d{θ}}{dt}}{\Vert{{vec{v}}\{t\}}\Vert}{sec(θ\{t\})}{csc(θ\{t\})}+g{csc(θ\{t\})}=0$$

Or:
$${\frac{d{θ}}{dt}}{sec(θ\{t\})}=\frac{g}{y\{t\}}$$

And I want to isolate $θ\{t\}$, and that’ll help me find $\Vert{\vec{v}\{t\}}\Vert$ too; 
Any ideas, anyone ?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Would you do us the favour to use MathJax for your formulæ,  please?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions

Comment: It might behoove you greatly, in terms of getting answers, to properly format your post using MathJax.  It is nearly unreadable as it is.  It looks like an engaging question but is just too hard to decipher as is.  Cheers!

Comment: Alright, guys ! I think I got it pretty well this time ! Now, I’m gonna for the answers (and rest a bit ; D).

Comment: Yes you did, much easier to decipher.  Thanks!